# How to ignore all characters after "controller/action" in an ASP.NET MVC route?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, url-routing

I would like my ASP.NET MVC4 application to only serve the base HTML markup for a specific page, and after that I'm processing everything else on client-side with knockout.js/history.js/AJAX, including the initial page load.

So when someone refers to URL `http://example.com/products/list/food/fruits`, the MVC router should simply ignore everything what is behind "products/list" and route the request to `ProductsController` and `List` action. Then on client-side I will handle the rest and load the requested data accordingly.

I was playing with the route definitions, I tried to completely skip the "products/list" route, I also tried to add a "products/list/*" route, but didn't have success yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an asterisk as part of the last variable in a route. For example, when configuring your routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ProductRoute",
    "products/list/{*otherArgs}",
    new { controller = "Products", action = "List" });
```

You can learn more in [MSDN's Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#handling_a_variable_number_of_segments_in_a_url_pattern) on routing under the section "Handling a Variable Number of Segments in a URL Pattern"

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create your own route.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
 routes.MapRoute("Products", "Products/{List}",
            new {controller = "Products", action = "List"}
            );
```

Note: I´m not sure if the other parameters are required in the route.